# Can't get localhost to work with my app

Tags: facebook

I've been struggling with this for a couple hours now and none of the answers I seem to find have done the trick for me, I want to integrate a Feed Dialog to my app and I'm testing it in localhost, the thing is I can't get it to work, the window opens and I'm told that I'm not in a valid URL for my app, but I've added localhost in the section it's supposed to go, [here is how my app basic settings look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXpFP.jpg), am I missing something? I really appreciate any help.

Comment: SiteURL is one URL. You can't make up your own syntax to specify more than one

Comment: Okay that makes sense, I was handed the app over from someone else and it was already like that, so I should change it to be just localhost while I do my tests and then return it to the production url?

Comment: Just create a test app instead https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-apps